# AWS EC2 IAM Role Credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Using the Node sdk for AWS, I'm trying to use the credentials and permissions given by the IAM role that is attached to the EC2 instance that my Node application is running on.

According to the sdk documentation, that can be done using the `EC2MetadataCredentials` class to assign the configuration properties for the sdk.

In the file that I'm using the sdk in to access a DynamoDB instance, I have the configuration code:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.EC2MetadataCredentials({
    httpOptions: { timeout: 5000 },
    maxRetries: 10,
    retryDelayOptions: { base: 200 }
})

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10'
})
```

However, when I trying to visit the web application I always get an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: d.default.EC2MetadataCredentials is not a constructor
>
> Uncaught TypeError: _awsSdk2.default.EC2MetadataCredentials is not a constructor

Even though that is the exact usage from the documentation! Is there something small that I'm missing?

---

#### Update:

Removing the `credentials` and `region` definitions from the file result in another error that'll say:

`Error: Missing region|credentials in config`

Comment: If you have a IAM role attached to an instance, credentials will be automatically supplied. You don't need to config the credentials. Can you try?

Comment: @helloV I have tried to just remove the credentials assignment, but then I get 'Missing credentials in config' error

Comment: All your code could be reduced to just 2 lines that should use the EC2 IAM role automatically: 
`import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();`

Comment: @MarkB When I remove the `region` and `credential` assignments, i get `Error: Missing (region|credentials) in config`

Comment: Are you sure you are actually running this on an EC2 server with am IAM role assigned to it?

Comment: @MarkB Yes i'm positive. I'm SSHed into the instance and running the node application, and there is an IAM role attached in the instance details

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant for you, but you do need to configure the EC2MetadataCredentials as it is not in the default ProviderChain ( search for  new AWS.CredentialProviderChain([  in node_loader.js in the sdk).
It seems you might have an old version of aws_sdk as that code works for me:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
...
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.EC2MetadataCredentials();
```

Comment: Accessing credentials this way returned iAM role with instance id appended to it. PLease see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686244/why-aws-ec2metadatacredentials-giving-wrong-role

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue where AWS SDK was not fetching credentials. According to the [documentation](https://If%20you%20configure%20your%20instance%20to%20use%20IAM%20roles,%20the%20SDK%20automatically%20selects%20the%20IAM%20credentials%20for%20your%20application,%20eliminating%20the%20need%20to%20manually%20provide%20credentials.), SDK should be able to automatically fetch the credentials.

> If you configure your instance to use IAM roles, the SDK automatically selects the IAM credentials for your application, eliminating the need to manually provide credentials.

I was able to solve the issue by manually fetching the credentials, and providing them directly wherever required (For MongoDB Atlas in my case):

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.getCredentials(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  // credentials not loaded
  else {
    console.log("Access key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
  }
});
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html

Although, why SDK is not not doing it automatically is still mystery to me. I will update the answer once I figure it out.